# Sometimes SaveOrUpdate using nhibernate skips random values to insert into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, nhibernate

I'm using Nhibernate `SaveOrUpdate` and during bulk insert it skips random values to insert each time.

I need to fix this what should I do?

[image: db.save(entityname,obj)]

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you - this isn't normal behaviour so its something specific to your system.

Comment: add you code to your question then we can help

Comment: All the values are coming each at a time but using saveorupdate skips sometimes so I tried using just save it was working fine for couple of months and now it is also causing the same issue

Comment: I have added the image of the code please check

Comment: SO would much rather that code was added as formatted text.

Comment: Hey actually I cannot copy the code from the server sorry

Comment: Or if you can give me any alternative of saveorupdate

Answer (score 1):

`SaveOrUpdateWithExceptionHandling` relating to a `ISession` raises some red flags.

With NHibernate, if your session throws an exception, then it is now in an *inconsistent state*, and should be [immediately disposed of](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions).

You cannot do "... with exception handling" in your transaction, and this *may* be a source of your errors. You certainly will need to revisit your approach to this problem.

In the case of an error (perhaps due to concurrency, it's kinda unclear what you are trying to do), then you need to roll back the entire transaction, dispose of the session and try again.

Comment: "...roll back the entire transaction and try again." - Just to emphasize, "try again" means with a *new* session, not just a new transaction.